# Traffic Light style light system

Tags: led

I work with deaf athletes and need a training start light system, it needs to be a box approx 15 - 25cm long 10cm wide with three different coloured lights green, Amber, red 
Battery operated from a lead 2meters long, switch or button operated - first press green light comes on, second press green lights goes off and amber lights comes on, third press Amber light goes off and red light comes.
I hope someone can help as it would greatly aid deaf sports

Comment: It might be the best project ever, but unfortunately SE is not intended to serve as a recruitment or design service.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdEUjU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Instead of using a button, use a 3-position rotary switch. No electronics required.*

[image]

*Figure 2. 12-way rotary switch. Move the stop-ring (under the nut) to required number of positions.*